# estoy intentando usar certbot ahora ya solo me falta la redirección

Tags: certificado-ssl, virtualhost

estoy usando puTTY en windows 10 y quiciera hacer una redireccion desde el virtual host

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   Redirect / https://www.yourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

quiciera saber que va exactamente en #etc, a que se refiere, no se que poner

Comment: Toda línea que comience con # quiere decir que está comentada, o sea no hay ningún valor, esa línea bien la puedes eliminar o continuar agregando parametros

Comment: si ya entendi ya pude hacerlo gracias! :) pero una pregunta mi sitio dice https://panetown.com sin "www." esto como lo afecta? porque si escribo panetown solo asi en google no me aparece la pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el posicionamiento de páginas si te afecta, ya que debe de haber una redirección, esto puedes hacerlo con el archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Puedes leer más aquí: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess